# colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish is not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, ios14

in Swift iOS 14 the delegate method colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish is only being triggered when i present the Color-Picker in full screen mode and dismiss it with the "X" button, is there a way to trigger this method when the user swipes down to dismiss the modal?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No i didn't, i had to use full screen instead.